# Replacing information in fixed length records in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice, immutability

Interestingly enough I found this exact question on this website - for the exact same homework problem no less- but a conclusion was never reached due to insufficient information about the problem. Hopefully, I will have better luck.

I am working on my Python 3 homework and I've come to a problem that I am really struggling with.

The exact prompt given is:

> "You will be passed the filename 'P', firstname 'F', lastname 'L',
>   and a new  birthday 'B'.    Load the fixed length record file in P,
>   search for F,L in the first  and change birthday to B.    Then save
>   the file."

The idea here being that we create a program to change a person's birthday from one unknown to another, using the variables given. Being the impatient person that I am I print()ed P - the file- and know that it is:

> Adam            Smith           11111985Theodore        Anderson
>   03201990Monty           Biscuit-Barrel  10181980Adam
>   Smithers        10101960Ruthy           Anderson        06062010

The spacing gets lost upon pasting, but the first and last names have a fixed length of 16 each, and the birthdays have a fixed length of 8.

The name of the individual who's birthday I am trying to change is:

> Adam Smithers

And that I am trying to change his birthday to:

> 00000000

I've tried replacing the birthday using slice (as, per our instruction, opening a text file in python turns the file into a string, and therefore immutabel). However, when I try the script:

```
with open(P) as p:
  new_file = p[0:141] + B + p[161:]
```

I receive the error message " '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable"

I've been trying to finagle this for a couple hours now, but haven't gotten any closer. Any suggestions would be appreciated at this point. Thank you

Comment: Hint: Read the whole file, split it by spaces, you'll get a new list, now make a new list stepping 3 elements of the last list at a time, now you've got a 2-dimensional array, figure the rest yourselves!

Answer (score 0):

From the homework's description I understand that you need to update the existing file. For that you can use a memory map: `mmap`.
Here's a partial code you can take and extend:

```
import mmap
import os

def memory_map(filename):
    size = os.path.getsize(filename)
    fd = os.open(filename, os.O_RDWR)
    return mmap.mmap(fd, size, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)

def update_file(P, F, L, B):
    with memory_map(P) as p:
        # Find the offset of the right record with F and L
        p[141:157] = B
```